# Is there a way to mock MassTransit IMediator for unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-5, masstransit, webapi

I'm using [MassTransit](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/mediator.html) Mediator in my project and I ran into a problem. Well, I would like to write unit tests for controller methods, but I don't know how to mock the IMediator object in the correct way to get me back the data from the GetResponse  method that I want to return.

I am using nunit and nsubstitute in the test project.

I tried to do it this way, but it doesn't give the desired results. In this case, the List is null.
IMediator object and controller initialization:

```c#
private PotionsController _potionsController;
private IMediator _mediator;
```

```c#
[SetUp]
public void SetUp() {
   _mediator = Substitute.For<IMediator>();
   _potionsController = new PotionsController(_potionsRepository, _mediator);
}
```

```c#
[Test]
public async Task GetAllPotions_WhenCalled_ReturnsListOfPotions() {
   var requestClient = Substitute.For<IRequestClient<IGetPotionsQuery>>();
   var response = Substitute.For<Response<IGetPotionsResponse>>();
   response.Message.Potions.Returns(new List<Potion>() {
      new Potion(Guid.NewGuid(), "Greater Arcane Protection Potion",
          "Absorbs 1950 to 3250 arcane damage. Lasts 1 hour. (2 Min Cooldown)",
          "Protection", 7.50m, 4),
      new Potion(Guid.NewGuid(), "Greater Frost Protection Potion",
          "Absorbs 1950 to 3250 frost damage. Lasts 1 hour.(2 Min Cooldown)",
          "Protection", 7.50m, 4)
      });
   requestClient.GetResponse<IGetPotionsResponse>(Arg.Any<IGetPotionsQuery>. 
      ()).Returns(response);
   _mediator.CreateRequestClient<IGetPotionsQuery>().Returns(requestClient);

   var actionResult = await _potionsController.GetAllPotions();
   var okObjectResult = actionResult.Result as OkObjectResult;
   var potions = okObjectResult?.Value as List<Potion>;

   Assert.That(potions, Is.Not.Null);
   Assert.That(potions.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));
}
```

Is there any way to properly mock `GetResponse<T>`? If I use the IMediator object's `Send<TRequest>` method in the controller method, it is enough to check in the test whether this method was called with the appropriate parameters? An example of how to solve this would be great. Thank you in advance for any hints and help.

Comment: Just my two cents, but it seems pointless to test the wiring without the logic behind it. You're basically creating a unit test to ensure you know how to call a method. Which is about as useful as unit testing a property getter. I wouldn't mock the mediator, I'd test the logic end-to-end.

Comment: Ok, so in this case there is no point in writing tests for these methods in this way. Is it better to test the handler with the MassTransit Test Harness?

Comment: Correct, though mediator and the in-memory test harness are two different things.